# To use QueryBuilder expressions is secured?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

There are few ways to create the same query:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$qb
    ->select('COUNT(u.id)')
    ->where('u.email = :email'))
    ->setParameter('email', $email)
    ->getQuery();
```

and:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$qb
    ->select('COUNT(u.id)')
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('u.email', $email))
    ->getQuery();
```

What case better to use and what case are more secure and more stable for SQL injections?

Comment: `setParameter` will use prepared statements, hence is safe, while `$qb->expr()->eq()` won't.

Comment: @Touki Thanks, but how can I secure second example?

Comment: `where($qb->expr()->eq('u.email', ':email'))->setParameter(':email', $email)` ?

Comment: @Touki, I think it must work, thanks! I try to use it

Comment: I strongly recommend reading of this article http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/security.html especially _Safe and Unsafe APIs for User Input_ section.